# Flash Builder 4.7 not launching Firefox v21.0 in OS X 10.8.4

Tags: firefox, flash-builder

Flash Builder 4.7 does not launch Firefox in OS X 10.8.4...

I noticed this first when upgrading my Macbook Air to 10.8.4 from 10.7.x. FB stopped working for Firefox, I thought it was originally due to Java 7. I downgraded to Java 6, it didn't matter.

I went out and bought a new Air, which also had 10.8.4 pre installed. I installed only Flash Builder and Firefox. Same problem.

Some Notes:

- If I cut and paste the application URL from the FB build 'bin' or
  'bin-debug' into Firefox, the application renders fine.
- If I cut and paste the application URL from the FB build 'bin-debug'
  into Firefox, the application renders fine, and if I invoke the
  debugger, I'm able to run the debugger on 127.0.0.1, including
  breakpoints and all expected function.
- I can invoke Firefox from the command line, and it comes up
  correctly, using the path inside the FB preferences for Firefox (ie /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin)
- Chrome and Safari work as expected, able to be invoked from FB in run and debug mode (chrome doesn't like debug, expected)

This tells me that FB is invoking Firefox, but it's not coming up. Is there anyway to troubleshoot this? Could it be a FB env issue? Is there a FB log file besides .metadata/.log, which shows nothing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The path indicated on some sites -

/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin

is incorrect - the path should be

/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox